# How can I reduce memory use when implementing an animation in UE4?

Tags: animation, optimization, unreal-4

We've already made a tank's track spline animation but it's using a lot of memory because it's implemented inside a tick function. So, it needs to check every second but as you may know it requires a lot of resources if there will be more than 10 tanks..

Is there an optimal solution for this problem? Have others faced these kind of problems?

It would be great if the solution was in blueprints.

Comment: It's worth remembering that the tick is called every frame, not every second so it your game is updating at 60fps, that's 60 updates every second.  It might be worth checking if it's possible to put a branch in your tick and only call an update event if it's actually needed.

Comment: What is a tank track spline animation?

Comment: Try showing us what you're trying to animate and where you're running into memory problems with it.